# Explanation of a step in evaluating $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} {\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

The evaluation of the Gaussian integral is standard in Undergraduate Calculus ( Calculus II ?). I am not really asking how to evaluate this integral, which can be done by appealing to Fubini's theorem. Rather I do not understand this statement.

> Note that $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ is integrable on $[0,+\infty)$. Indeed, $f(x) = O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$, thus ...

This statement preceeds, the line before Fubini is applied. I am not sure of the significance of "Big-Oh" here.  I do not know how to use the above method to show a function is integrable. Could someone help me ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you copy and paste a more complete paragraph which contains the "big O" to your post?

Comment: From $f(x)=O(1/x)$, it does not follow that $f$ is integrable, as $f(x)= 1/x$ shows

Comment: Sorry! That should read $O(\frac{1}{x^2})$. Unfortunately, that is the only mention of big-O in the paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want to know. $\exp(-x^2)<\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x$ large enough and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a mistake, and the author meant $x^2$ instead of $x$. Indeed note that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}} = 0$$
so $f(x) = O(\frac{1}{x^2})$. Now for any $h > 0$ we have
$$ \int_h^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} =  \frac{1}{h}$$
now by the above there exists $m > 0$ such that for $x > m$ we have
$$ e^{-x^2} \leq \frac{M}{x^2}$$
and now it follows that
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \ dx = \int_0^m e^{-x^2} \ dx + \int_m^\infty e^{-x^2} \ dx$$
and again by the above and since $e^{-x^2}\le1$ for every $x$,
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \ dx \leq \int_0^m e^{-x^2} \ dx + \frac{M}{m}\leq m + \frac{M}{m}$$
so the indefinite integral converges.

Comment: Thank you! I was fooled by the presence of big-Oh. As you and phomuex before, pointed out, there was a typo. Extrapolating from phomuex comment, I understood, what you have just confirmed. Thank you very much! :)